# Is Microsoft Documentation incorrect for Assembly.LoadFile method?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection, fusion

I have this code which tries to load all assemblies in a folder and then for each assembly, also check if all of its dependencies too can be found in the same folder.

```
private static string searchDirectory = @"C:\Users\Anon\Downloads\AssemblyLoadFilePOC_TESTFOLDER";

    private static readonly List<string> errors = new List<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 1)
            searchDirectory = args[1];

        var files = Directory
            .GetFiles(searchDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".dll", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || s.EndsWith(".exe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                AssemblyLoadHandler.Enable(Path.GetDirectoryName(file));

                Assembly assembly = null;
                if (File.Exists(file) && Path.GetExtension(file) == ".dll")
                {
                    assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
                }
                else
                {
                    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
                    assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(fileInfo.FullName);
                }

                ValidateDependencies(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), assembly, errors);
            }
            catch (BadImageFormatException e)
            {
                errors.Add(e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errors.Add(ex.Message); ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the AssemblyLoadHandler class which contains an event handler for Assembly Resolve event.

```
public static class AssemblyLoadHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates whether the load handler is already enabled.
    /// </summary>
    private static bool enabled;

    /// <summary>
    /// Path to search the assemblies from
    /// </summary>
    private static string path;

    /// <summary>
    /// Enables the load handler.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Enable(string directoryPath)
    {
        path = directoryPath;
        if (enabled)
        {
            return;
        }

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += LoadAssembly;
        enabled = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A handler for the <see cref="AppDomain.AssemblyResolve"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="args">The event arguments.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="Assembly"/> instance fot the resolved assembly, or <see langword="null" /> if the assembly wasn't found.
    /// </returns>
    private static Assembly LoadAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        // Load managed assemblies from the same path as this one - just take the DLL (or EXE) name from the first part of the fully qualified name.
        var filePath = Path.Combine(path, args.Name.Split(',')[0]);

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(filePath + ".dll"))
            {
                return Assembly.LoadFile(filePath + ".dll");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(filePath + ".exe"))
            {
                return Assembly.LoadFile(filePath + ".exe");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's the ValidateDependencies method which tries to load all dependencies of an assembly:

```
private static void ValidateDependencies(string searchDirectory, Assembly assembly, List<string> errors)
    {
        var references = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();

        foreach (var r in references)
        {
            var searchDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(searchDirectory, r.Name + ".dll");
            var runtimeDirectoryPath = Directory.GetFiles(RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(), r.Name + ".dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists(searchDirectoryPath) && (runtimeDirectoryPath == null || runtimeDirectoryPath.Length == 0))
                {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("Dependency " + r.Name + " could not be found.", r.FullName);
                }
                else
                {
                    Assembly foundAssembly = null;

                    if (File.Exists(searchDirectoryPath))
                    {
                        foundAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(searchDirectoryPath);

                        if (foundAssembly.GetName().Version != r.Version && !r.Flags.HasFlag(AssemblyNameFlags.Retargetable))
                            foundAssembly = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foundAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(runtimeDirectoryPath[0]);
                    }

                    if (foundAssembly == null)
                    {
                        throw new FileNotFoundException("Required version of dependency " + r.Name + " could not be found.", r.FullName);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                errors.Add(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

For testing, I have only put 2 assemblies in my test path: `C:\Users\Anon\Downloads\AssemblyLoadFilePOC_TESTFOLDER`:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll having assembly version 5.0.17.0
and ONE of its dependency: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll having asembly version 5.0.0.0

Note that Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll version 5.0.17.0 has a dependency on Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll version 5.0.0.0

Just to test if my event handler for Assembly Resolve event is working correctly, I added this assembly binding redirect in my app config for this console application.

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
```

This application is a .NET 4.8 console application, when I run it without the binding redirect in the app config, as expected, the Assembly Resolve event is not fired. However, when I do add the redirect, Assembly Resolve event is fired multiple times and the application eventually crashes with Stackoverflow exception.

Quoting from MSDN docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/resolve-loads#the-correct-way-to-handle-assemblyresolve

> When resolving assemblies from the AssemblyResolve event handler, a
> StackOverflowException will eventually be thrown if the handler uses
> the Assembly.Load or AppDomain.Load method calls. **Instead, use
> LoadFile or LoadFrom methods, as they do not raise the AssemblyResolve
> event.**

As you can see, I am using Assembly.LoadFile method in my event handler and yet, the event keeps getting fired multiple times. Is the documentation incorrect? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I just noticed that when my event handler is called, args.RequestingAssembly is NULL. I suspect this might be because of this.

Comment: You are using Assembly.LoadFrom this might fire resolve events. If you remove LoadFrom are these events still fired?

Comment: @AloisKraus But the documentation specifically states that both LoadFile and LoadFrom do not fire the AssemblyResolve event. I tried switching between LoadFile and LoadFrom, and again got the stackoverflow exception. I even commented out the ValidateDependencies method from Main().

Comment: can you show the stacktrace which flows over?

Answer (score 4):

Nope, the documentation you mentioned is just fine! Pay attention that in the documentation, they create a new AppDomain called "Test";

```cs
AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test");
ad.AssemblyResolve += MyHandler;
```

If you create a new AppDomain and use it instead of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain`, your problem will be solved.

But let's say that for some reason you want to use the current AppDomain for some reason. We know that there is an uncontrolled recursive call hell which causes the stack overflow exception. How can we get rid of it? Simple! Just unsubscribe your handler method from `AssemblyResolve` event before loading assembly in the handler;

```cs
private static Assembly AssemblyResolveHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= AssemblyResolveHandler;

    return Assembly.LoadFile("SomeAssembly.dll");
}
```

This is the minimal code that I've derived from your code;

```cs
private const string SearchDirectory = @"...\AssemblyLoadFilePOC_TESTFOLDER";

private static void Main()
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(SearchDirectory))
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolveHandler;

        try
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);

            foreach (var referenceAssembly in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
            {
                var referenceAssemblyPath = Path.Combine(SearchDirectory, referenceAssembly.Name + ".dll");
                if (!File.Exists(referenceAssemblyPath))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                try
                {
                    var loadedAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(referenceAssemblyPath);

                    Console.WriteLine("Reference Assembly Version: " + referenceAssembly.Version);
                    Console.WriteLine("Loaded Assembly Version: " + loadedAssembly.GetName().Version);
                    Console.WriteLine("Is Reference Assembly Retargetable: " + referenceAssembly.Flags.HasFlag(AssemblyNameFlags.Retargetable));
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException)
                {
                    // We already check if the file exists or not in the beginning of foreach loop.
                    // So if we face any FileNotFoundException, it's because of version mismatch.
                    Console.WriteLine($"Required version of dependency {referenceAssembly.Name} could not be found.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            // Same as above. We get files from the folder and then try to load them.
            // So if we face any FileNotFoundException, it's because of version mismatch.
            Console.WriteLine($"Redirected version of assembly {file} could not be found.");
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}

private static Assembly AssemblyResolveHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= AssemblyResolveHandler;

    return Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(SearchDirectory, args.Name.Split(',')[0]) + ".dll");
}
```

Output when no assembly redirecting is used - which commenting out unsubscribing line in `AssemblyResolveHandler` method has no effect on;

```
Reference Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
Loaded Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
Is Reference Assembly Retargetable: False
```

Output when assembly redirecting is used and commented out that line;

```
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
```

Output when assembly redirecting is used and uncommented out that line;

```
Required version of dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions could not be found.
Redirected version of assembly ...\AssemblyLoadFilePOC_TESTFOLDER\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll could not be found.
```

**Edit:** I just saw your comment about ResolveEventArgs.RequestingAssembly is being null. I'd like to explain it but it's a different thing and I don't want to make my answer longer. For more information about that, [click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500966/resolveeventargs-requestingassembly-is-null).

Comment: I missed that part about creation of new app domain in the MSDN sample code. But, the documentation does not state that Assemly.LoadFIle and Assembly.LoadFrom behave in a different manner when using a separate app domain (not the current one). So, why is it that these methods are firing the AssemblyResolve event when I use them in the current app domain? Continued in next comment.

Comment: I understand that unsubscribing the event handler before loading an assembly will fix the StackOverflow exception, but I want to know why is this even a problem? Why is this even being raised multiple times for the same assembly when the docs say LoadFrom and LoadFile do not raise this event?

Comment: For the RequestingAssembly being null, I did come across the answer that you have linked, however, I don't understand it. It says, use LoadFile instead of LoadFrom, but even then I found RequestingAssembly to be NULL. Will try this again and update here.

Comment: WOuld also like to mention that RequestingAssembly was not NULL for both LoadFrom and LoadFIle when I tried exactly the same code in .NET 6. THen I came across this issue on github https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/12668 but I don't understand why it was closed. Looks like its still an issue in .NET Framework 4.8